# How do you express the rate of change with radius of an expression $x$, at a given radius in a gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, notation, calculus

Is it enough to say $dx/dr$, and specify an expression that x refers to, or do you need also to say something like (dx/dr)(r), because it is at a given radius?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you, if you want to write down the rate at which an expression such as GM/r^2 is changing at a given radius, is it enough to write it as dx/dr, and specify separately that x = GM/r^2? Or is there a need to show that this is for a particular radius, so perhaps it might be (dx/dr(r)), and specify what x represents.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the expression $$F=\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$$ and you want to compute its derivative with respect to $r$. You could just write,

$$\dfrac{dF}{dr}=-\dfrac{2GMm}{r^3}$$

You know that you differentiate with respect to $r$ because of the $\dfrac{d}{d\color{red}r}$.

However, there isn't anything wrong with writing
$\dfrac{dF(r)}{dr}$ or $\dfrac{dF}{dr}(r)$. The latter notation is actually useful for evaluating the derivative. I.e. you want to see what $dF/dr$ is when $r=3$ then you could write: $$\dfrac{dF}{dr}(3) \quad\text{or}\quad \dfrac{dF}{dr} \Bigr\rvert_{r = 3}$$

I'd explore the following wikipedia article: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Leibniz's_notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Leibniz%27s_notation).

Comment: And is it formally ok to use x to represent an expression, if you don't have another way to refer to it, such as F?

Comment: So long as you declare your variables, you can use whatever (of course don't be intentionally confusing or renaming quantities that already have common symbols associated to them). But I would not use $x$, simply because it's usually the independent variable. There is usually a letter that is related to the quantity you're using, so I'd use that as a variable.  But there are loose conventions. E.g. if it's an angle, use something like $\theta$ or $\alpha$. If it's a potential, then use $U$ etc.  There will almost always be a decent variable that is related to the quantity it represents